# Regarding reading huge csv file using python with about 16 million rows

Tags: python

I am new to python and i am trying to do sentiment analysis of twitter tweets of bitcoin, but the data which I got is very huge and have around 16 million rows and about 4 GB in size.

I am not sure how to read this file using python.

It is a csv file

can you please help me regarding this.

**Dataset link** - https://www.kaggle.com/alaix14/bitcoin-tweets-20160101-to-20190329

Comment: You should look into [Dask](https://dask.org/) I'm voting to close this question as there are numerous guides on the internet you can find on the first page of google which will go into greater detail than a post could.

Answer (score 0):

did you try compressing the file as .gz and open it via pandas

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.gz', compression='gzip', header=0, sep=' ', quotechar='"', error_bad_lines=False)
```